# Draw on a Canvas via mouse and touch

Tags: html, canvas, touch

I want to draw on a canvas, works great with a mouse, but how do I have to modify the code to make it run on iPad or Nexus as well?

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/FgNQk/6/)

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width  = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.width = width;

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        this.down = true;   
        this.X = e.pageX ;
        this.Y = e.pageY ;
    }, 0);

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        this.down = false;          
    }, 0);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      
        if(this.down) {
             with(ctx) {
                beginPath();
                moveTo(this.X, this.Y);
                lineTo(e.pageX , e.pageY );
                ctx.lineWidth=1;
                stroke();
             }
             this.X = e.pageX ;
             this.Y = e.pageY ;
        }
    }, 0);
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you only have to exchange 'mousedown' and write 'touchdown' then it will work for iPad.

Comment: I tried it with touchdown, but it does not work: [link] http://jsfiddle.net/FgNQk/7/

Answer (score 9):

This is an HTML file that works to draw both mouse and touch events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  // get the canvas element and its context
  var canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var isIdle = true;
  function drawstart(event) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
    isIdle = false;
  }
  function drawmove(event) {
    if (isIdle) return;
    context.lineTo(event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
    context.stroke();
  }
  function drawend(event) {
    if (isIdle) return;
    drawmove(event);
    isIdle = true;
  }
  function touchstart(event) { drawstart(event.touches[0]) }
  function touchmove(event) { drawmove(event.touches[0]); event.preventDefault(); }
  function touchend(event) { drawend(event.changedTouches[0]) }

  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchend', touchend, false);        

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', drawstart, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drawmove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', drawend, false);

}, false); // end window.onLoad
</script></head><body  encoding='utf8'>
  <canvas id='sketchpad' width='500' height='500' style='border:1px solid #777'/>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The events you need to use are `touchstart`, `touchend`, and `touchmove`, which should correspond with the functions above. I don't know if events can be stacked as easily in plain JS as in jQuery, but you should be able to support both mouse and touch either by turning each event into functions:

```
var myMoveEvent = function (e) {
    if(this.down) {
         with(ctx) {
            beginPath();
            moveTo(this.X, this.Y);
            lineTo(e.pageX , e.pageY );
            ctx.lineWidth=1;
            stroke();
         }
         this.X = e.pageX ;
         this.Y = e.pageY ;
    }
}

canvas
    .addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        myMoveEvent(e);
    }, 0)
    .addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        myMoveEvent(e);
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using events `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove`, but it is more complex, because coordinates are not in pageX and pageY, but all fingers coordinates are in the array:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width  = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.width = width;

canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  this.down = true;   
  this.X = e.touches[0].pageX ;
  this.Y = e.touches[0].pageY ;
}, 0);

canvas.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
  this.down = false;          
}, 0);

canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  if(this.down) {
    with(ctx) {
      beginPath();
      moveTo(this.X, this.Y);
      lineTo(e.touches[0].pageX , e.touches[0].pageY );
      ctx.lineWidth=1;
      stroke();
    }
    this.X = e.touches[0].pageX ;
    this.Y = e.touches[0].pageY ;
  }
}, 0);
```

but this not solve common problem, to make it both mouse and touch compatible. I searched for solution and found this solution, if you're interested: http://bencentra.com/code/2014/12/05/html5-canvas-touch-events.html
Also if the task will be more complex, you must find solution for default smartphone browsers behaviour that when trigger touchstart browsers also triggers additional events `mousedown` + `mouseup` + `click` (it is for compatibility with non-touch sites). Using `Event.preventDefault()` can disable this behaviour temporarily for actual touch event.